# Most effective use of multiple build agents in TeamCity where elapsed time of all build configs is greather than available time

Tags: automation, scheduled-tasks, teamcity

I have 4 build agents and almost 30 configurations (and growing) and  the combined elapsed build time for these configurations is over 120 hours, so the build agent time I have available for these agents is less than the time to run all of the builds once.

I should add these build configurations run integration tests and are not CI builds (although CI  is practiced in my organisation).

There are a couple of rules any schedule must abide by:

1. A number of build configurations must be ran at least every day
2. 1 build agent must be free between the hours of 0800 to 1600 for ad-hoc build configurations to be ran

My current strategy for scheduling the build configurations is

1. Time build configurations to specific build agents using agent requirements
2. For 3 agents plan out 20 hours a day with build configurations chosen to run one after another at unique set times
3. For 1 agent plan out only the hours outside of 0800 to 1600 with build configurations chosen to run one after another at unique set times during these hours
4. Schedule the builds I don't need to run every day to run alternate days

Is this the most effective way to use the build agents? Would I be better off not scheduling specific and unique start times for the builds? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!